# How to maintain confidentiality of transformed media in two-host configuration?

Tags: asp.net, security, configuration, servlets, host

Let's say I have two machines, A and B, on the public internet (not an intranet).

Machine A has a web server that hosts unencrypted images of confidential documents.

Machine B hosts an ASP.net or Java servlet page for allowing manipulations of those images.

The URL of media on Machine A can be passed to the page on Machine B, which can then manipulate the image.

How can Machine B provide a guarantee that it does not retain any of the confidential information being passed to it from Machine A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Machine B has to have access to an unencrypted version of the documents from Machine A, and Machine A cannot trust the code running on Machine B, I can't think of any way to guarantee to Machine A that Machine B has destroyed all copies of what was sent it.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of and, yes, the documents are unencrypted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any way to guarantee that.  With [deniable encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deniable_encryption), if they went public with a document you could plausibly deny having ever sent it.

But I can't think of any way of technologically forcing them to destroy the document after doing processing.

Comment: The documents are unencrypted. I didn't think this was possible but I wanted to check.